# The summer training or (just) summer training

Tags: sentence-construction, articles, definite-article

Should we use **the summer training** or just **summer training** in the paragraph. As per me **training** is a noun and before singular noun we have to use an article and I am using **the** because I am talking about a specific training for engineers, I also know that before very common nouns we avoid articles, like bed, school, bus, university, so if you say we should use **summer training** then please give me a valid reason.

> Company(name) has been providing **the summer training** for engineers
>   since 2010. We have been giving completely professional atmosphere for
>   engineers to complete **the summer training** with practical knowledge.
>   Our each faculty has a great experience in **the education field**. We
>   make sure you get all the important resources to make your summer
>   training a learning and an enjoyable summer training. You may call or
>   email us to get your confirmation about **the training**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not only about the noun is singular (or not). You should also check whether the noun is countable or not. (For example, "training" is an uncountable noun.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Okay, so before uncountable nouns, we never use "the article" right?

Comment: No, I didn't say that. That's a different issue. Whether you should use "the" or not depends on the [definiteness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness). The article "the" is the definite article in English. Please wait a little longer. I'm sure that you will get answers from others soon.

Comment: @Damkerng: I was kinda hoping *you* would provide the answer! (I don't think I have time right now.) So far as I'm concerned, the first ***the*** before ***training*** has got to go (they could either be kept or not for the other two). But I think "countability" is relevant, in that ***fields*** are countable, and that one *needs* the article.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Though both StoneyB's answer and FumbleFinger's comment have already discussed the four "the"s in your question, I would like to provide additional information about articles, in hope that it'd be useful.

Using articles properly is difficult for learners, especially the learners who speak languages that do not have articles. Thus, it's very useful for these learners (myself included) to know the **"two basic rules"** listed in *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan, under entry 62.1:

> - To say 'You know which I mean', we put *the* before a noun.
>     *I've been to **the doctor**.* (You know which one: my doctor.)
>     *Have you fed **the dogs**?* (You know which ones I mean.)
>     *Could you pass **the salt**?* (You can see the salt that I want.)
> - When we can't say 'You know which I mean', we:
>
>   - put *a/an* before a singular countable noun (see 65).
>       *There's **a rat** in the kitchen!*
>       *I need **an envelope**.*
>   - put no article with a plural or uncountable noun.
>       *She's afraid of **rats**.*
>       *I need **help**.*

In short, ask yourself "Does the reader know which I mean?",

- If YES, use *the* before that noun. (*Have you fed **the dogs**?*)
- If NO, ask yourself "Is it a singular countable noun?"

  - If YES, use *a/an* before that noun. (*I need **an envelope**.*)
  - If NO, use no article before that noun. (*She's afraid of **rats**.*)

Please note that these two basic rules, though cover most typical cases, are not complete. There are lots of exceptions and the real practices are so complex as StoneyB wrote.

---

Following the two basic rules, and knowing that ***[training](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/training)*** is uncountable and ***[field](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/field)*** is countable, it's now easier to see why the first ***"<del>the</del> summer training"***(1) in your question is incorrect.

> Company(name) has been providing **<del>the</del> summer training**(1) for engineers since 2010. We have been giving completely professional atmosphere for engineers to complete **the summer training**(2) with practical knowledge. Our each faculty has a great experience in **the education field**(3). We make sure you get all the important resources to make your summer training a learning and an enjoyable summer training. You may call or email us to get your confirmation about **the training**(4).

It's because you've never mentioned this summer training before, so the reader has no idea "which summer training" you mean. Writing "the summer training" in your first sentence will make it sound like your summer training is the "only" summer training in the world.

The other two "training"s: ***"the summer training"***(2) and ***"the training"***(4) are acceptable because "summer training" has already been mentioned in (1), so the reader now knows which "summer training" or "training" you are talking about. However, "this" might be a better choice, as StoneyB explained.

The part ***"the education field"***(3) needs "the", because the word *field* is a countable noun, which means you need an article. To pick between "an education field" and "the education field", you might need to consider if "education fields" makes sense. (If you think you can say "an education field", you should also be able to imagine several "education fields".) And since "education fields" might not make much sense in your case, it's better to write "the education field".--Think of it like this: "It's a field. Which field? It's the education field."

Comment: Yes, it's an excellent answer. Those two "basic rules" (which I would have struggled to identify so clearly myself) cover the vast majority of cases learners actually *need* to become familiar with. So it's good that you stick to those and avoid digressing into "exceptions" that might be interesting to a few (advanced learners and even native speakers), but are likely to be just intimidating/confusing to many more of what I imagine are our target audience. (My comment ploy to "tickle" you into answering obviously worked out well! :)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Thanks. Your answer is very helpful, I appreciate it a lot. So can I use a summer training (first time) and then the summer training (second time)?

Comment: @user62015 You should use "summer training" (no article, because "training" is uncountable) the first time. As for the second time, you can use either "the summer training" or "this summer training".

Answer (score 13):

It's not so simple as a matter of 'countability' or 'number'; in fact the practices which govern use of articles are so complex and so tied to specific situations they cannot easily be summarized in a few rules.

The most useful rule I have ever encountered about use of the definite article is that it always refers the NP it heads to a specific instance which you are about to define or which has already been introduced into the discourse. Your readers already know which instance of NP you are talking about, or will know by the end of the sentence.

Consequently, in your example, the first *summer training* should **not** have a definite article: *summer training* is a new topic, and your sentence does not go on to establish that you are talking about a specific instance of *summer training*.

It's OK for the second instance of *summer training* to have the definite article. That would indicate that you are talking about the *summer training* defined in the previous sentence: the summer training which your organization offers for engineers. In this case, however, most of us would not use *the* but a demonstrative pronoun, *this* or *that*. This is because *the training* is somewhat ambiguous: it may mean either “training of a particular sort” or “training taken on a particular occasion”. Using *this* resolves the ambiguity because it points to “training of a particular sort” you just wrote about.

The *the* in *the education field* is correct, because you are not speaking about *field* in general (which would be very odd English!) but about a particular, definite *field*: *the **education** field*.

Comment: Thanks, you made the point but I still need your help. I used the because I would send this matter to some colleges and those colleges know that in which fields we offer training. So still I should say summer training not the summer training.

Comment: I like how your fourth paragraph contrasts the possibility of using ***this*** instead of ***the*** at that particular point in the text.

Comment: @user62015 Yes, still no article. Your message seems to be initiating a new discourse, not responding to a previous question, so you have to lay a new 'foundation'.

Comment: Also, see @DamkerngT.'s answer, which is the best discussion of articles I have seen on this site.

Comment: I have my own question, If I want to introduce mysefl to a new friend for the first time, should I use the : "Hi, I work in (THE) education field. How about you?"

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, **the summer training** is a part of company's **regular practice** *(check - has been providing...)* and thus it has taken the definite article. So, no matter first or last time, it'll be *the summer training* until the company ends that practice of providing the training. Maybe, the whole thing goes as a *title.* "The summer training will start in a few days.", "The summer training ends up with a lot of prizes and surprises.", and so on...

The statement is probably coming from one of the authorities who address *the summer training* as their ritual/trend to make their engineers better.

Rest all *the's* are mentioned by others.

Comment: Yes, that was the case, I appreciate your help. it was helpful.