# No definite article before 'topics' in "touching on topics" in this sentence?

Tags: definite-article

> ([Quora](http://www.quora.com/Harvard-University/What-do-Harvard-and-MIT-students-think-of-edX)) Eric Lander chose lectures that would give the audience a perfectly relevant introduction to Biology, touching on **topics** in his research in the Human Genome Project.

Where is the definite article? Should not it be **the topics**, because these are the exact topics

Comment: First, don't keep *on* with *topics*; it's with *touch*. *touch on* is a phrasal verb!

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17430/the-summer-training-or-just-summer-training/17433#17433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the definite article would imply that the introduction would be touching on **all** topics that are covered in the mentioned research.

Without the article, or rather *with* the *indefinite plural* article (which in English happens to be a *null* article), the writer indicates that the introduction will touch topics from the research, but it may not be all of the topics in the research.

Maybe another example will make it a bit clearer. I'm on apples today somehow, so bear with me.

I like to eat apples. I know a farmer who grows them. Now, if I eat an apple, and it comes from that farmer:

> *The* apple I ate was *an* apple from the farmer.

If I eat several apples, both the *definite* and *indefinite* article change to the plural:

> *The apples* I ate were apples from the farmer.

If in any of the sentences I would use the definite instead of the indefinite article, the meaning of the sentence would change dramatically:

> The apple I ate was the apple from the farmer.

Either the farmer only had one apple, or possibly, I had earlier obtained several apples, but only *one* was from that farmer.

> The apples I ate were the apples from the farmer.

Now I ate all the farmer's apples (burp), or indeed, I had earlier obtained several apples, some of which came from the farmer, and I ate those.

Comment: Hmm... It is something new for me.

Answer (score 0):

Putting articles is always tricky and even learned people miss them sometimes.

Placing the *definite* articles reflects that he's very clear about the topics he'd be covering or touching on. However, practically it's not possible as there could be innumerable topics to cover.

Remember, if you want to specify anything *general* in mass, drop the definite article *the*. I had read this example somewhere which is very useful.

> I know that elephants are dangerous - would imply *elephants* **in general**. 
>   I know that the elephants are dangerous - would imply that elephants of a particular group (maybe, **the elephants** in **this zoo or area** are dangerous).

Considering this, the author wanted to talk about **topics** covered in his research **in general** and not **the topics** those are countable and given names to.

**Note:** One would also argue that **the topics** is correct as well. I don't deny. *I'm covering the topics I have prepared in this presentation* is **fine**. However, the site is Quora and there you don't expect the content to be flawless.

Comment: But **the elephant** is a dangerous animal.  This could mean elephants in general.

Comment: @snailplane true but nobody said that!