# difference between the two sentences ,totally confusing for me

Tags: articles

What is the difference between "pieces of information" and "the pieces of information"
e.g.:

- The wages of sin is death.
- why not?___Wages of sin is death.

Is there any method to overcome these kind of problems?

Try to explain instead of pulling leg ....

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE! If you had any questions about the workings of the site, you can always visit the [help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) or take a [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site.|| "A method to solve these problems" I estimate to be too broad, but a good answerer may sum it up for you. (You do realize that articles can't just be taught in just a few books.)

Comment: Understanding articles is one of the hardest things in English Language. For instance, you should've wrote "pulling **my** leg", because most times you need to use some [determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner) before the single countable noun **leg**. Articles are determiners too.

Comment: Indeed @CopperKettle. A really nice way to learn about articles is a mother language close to English.

Comment: I think "The wages of sin is death." is a set phrase that is well known as is. If your question is about the use (or not) of *the*, this is probably not a good example. If you enter "the omit" in the search box, you can see a number of related questions.

Comment: @user153963 The "two basic rules" in this answer, http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/17433/3281, will help you to get on the right track.

Comment: I have rolled this question back to before someone added tags referring to **articles**. It is not clear from what the user posted **what problem(s)** the user is having. As such, I have also close-voted the question until the user identifies what *specific issue(s)* the user is talking about. It's obvious to native speakers that *The wages of sin is death* has non-normal grammar to it. The article tags make it seem like the user is asking about articles only, but that is unclear from the actual content.

Answer (score 2):

'The pieces of information' is specific, possibly addressing something which has previously been mentioned.

'Pieces of information' is general, not specified.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the definite article "the" means that a specific object (or set of objects) is being referred to.  In the singular, when the definite article is not needed (that is, when a specific instance of an object is not being referred to), then the indefinite article (a or an) is used.  There is no plural indefinite article, so when the definite article is not needed ("the" is both singular and plural), no article is used.

Some context would help to say which of your constructions is appropriate, but to give some examples:  "I received **a** piece of information" means that the speaker received one piece of information, but nothing about that information is specified.  "I received **the** piece of information" would be used if it is assumed (from prior knowledge or context) that the listener knows what piece of information the speaker is referring to.  Likewise, "I received pieces of information" is completely generic with regards to the nature of the information, whereas "I received the pieces of information" is in reference to specific pieces.

In "The wages of sin is death", a specific instance is being referred to.  As a rule of thumb, if the thing in question is being described in particular, then the definite article will probably be used.  "There are pieces of information in the document." v/s "The pieces of information describe what happened." In context, the quote isn't meant to imply that death is only one of many results of sin, but the only one, hence the definite article.

Answer (score 0):

As MatthewW says, "the" indicates that you are referring to a specific thing or set of things, while "a" in the singular, or no article in the plural, indicates a non-specific thing. He gave a good discussion of "pieces of information".

Let me see if I can help out with "wages of sin".

First, note that this quote is 500 years old. The language has changed since then. And it is a translation from another language -- Greek -- so it's liable to be awkward. So while in modern English "wages" is normally understood to be a plural verb, here it is being used as a singular, as can be seen from the singular verb "is". Most modern speakers would say, for example, "My wages ARE paid in cash", not "My wages IS paid in cash."

So that said, the choice of article is therefore between "the" and "a", and not "the" and no article, as it would be if the noun was plural.

So to the point, Ask yourself, Are the "wages" being discussed here specific or general?

If the writer had said, "A wage of sin is death", then the wage would be general. This would be a much weaker statement. It implies that there might be many just outcomes from sin, only one of which is death. Maybe sometimes sin deserves death and sometimes it doesn't. But "The wages of sin is death" says there is only one just outcome, and this is it. It is a much stronger statement. If you sin, you deserve to die. Period, end of story. Very different from, "well, maybe sometimes, depending on the circumstances" etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what specific problem(s) you are asking about.

If you are asking about the grammar of *The wages of sin is death*, then the answer is that this sentence is a fixed sentence in English. It is used in many translations of the Bible into English.

If you are asking about *articles* and the difference between the *definite article (the)* and the *zero-article*, you should probably choose another sentence than *the wages of sin is death*, since this sentence is unigue. However, its use of **the** can still be explained.

For common nouns in English, we need to make either a definite or indefinite reference to them.

Both *pieces* and *wages* are count nouns in the plural.

For plural count nouns, we use the zero-article to make an indefinite reference. When we do this, we are not talking about any specific *pieces* or *wages*; we are also being indefinite as to the number of *pieces* or *wages*.

For example,

> Pieces of information were discovered over time.

This refers to some indefinite number of *pieces*. We just mean some number greater than 1. As such, this is an indefinite reference. We are also not referring to any specific pieces of information.

When we want to make a definite reference, we can use the definite article *the*; we can also use the demonstrative pronouns (this, that, these, those); we  can also use possessive pronouns (such as *my* and *your*).

> The pieces of information were discovered over time.

Thid is a definite reference. As definite reference is also *specific*. So we are talking about specific *pieces*. We are also talking about *all* the pieces unless we specify otherwise.

Now, what is a definite reference? A definite reference is one that the speaker or author makes when be assumes his hearer or reader can uniquely identify *which* 'pieces' he is taking about.

So, again with *wages* (with the zero-article) we are not talking about specific wages. They could be any wages.

With *the wages* we are talking about definite (the reader knows which wages) and specific *wages* (not just any wages).

Why not 'Wages of sin'? Well  you can say that, but no one would know *which* 'wages' you were talking about. Are they your wages  my wages, the Jews' wages, the Gentiles' wages, some wages, all wages, wages from yesterday, wages from today, unfair wages, leftover wages,...

With **The** wages, the author assumes you know **exactly which wages** he is talking about. He has either mentioned them before; he is about to mention them; or he thinks you can identify them from context, from shared information, or from general knowledge about the universe.