# About article before position of job

Tags: articles

I want to ask about a article before a position of job, because I have problem for using it. My sentence looks that:

> My position was ***the/a/an/none*** e-shop back-end  and  front-end  software developer.

Comment: [The two basic rules](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/17433/3281) I posted here once could be useful. Another note: the choice between *a* and *an* depends on how we pronounce the noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not actually a single answer to this... it depends on the company structure, which you haven't included in your question, but that's ok.

Here's your sentence:

> My position was _____ e-shop back-end and front-end software developer.

If you were the **only** person at that company with that job title, the correct article is "the".

> My position was **the** e-shop back-end and front-end software developer.

Now, if you were one of two or more people with this position, then you would use the indefinite article. Here, the choice is between "a" and "an". The rule is

- Use "a" when proceeding a consonant **sound**
- Use "an" when proceeding a vowel **sound**

In your case, e-shop is a vowel sound, so you'd go with "an".

> My position was **an** e-shop back-end and front-end software developer.

You **can** use neither article, though, if you wish. Because this position is sort of your "title", you could certainly opt to exclude them.

> My position was e-shop back-end and front-end software developer.

If it helps, you can imagine "e-shop back-end and front-end software developer" is in quotes but don't include the quotes on your resume/CV.

---

As an added note, in the versions **with** articles, you don't necessarily need the word "position":

> I was the/an e-shop back-end and front-end software developer.

This version is perfectly fine and (to my ears) sounds slightly better.

Comment: Generally, you'd **mention specifically** that you were the *only* developer. "I was **the only** front-end software developer int the company".  Without 'only', practically, it's difficult to *guess* when we hear this from someone.

Comment: @MaulikV I'm not a programmer but, in general, I don't agree. "Only" certainly serves to *emphasize* the fact that you're **the** developer but it isn't required. That's part of why "the" exists.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use *designation*.

And, you should use 'an' because of the vowel following the article. Just like *an eCommerce website*, *an email* and so on.

> My designation was **an** e-shop backend and front end software developer