# Article before a plural

Tags: articles, plural-forms

I found a sentence on an English grammar book. I am confused why an article is used before a plural.

> Each of ***the*** following sentences is preceded by a bare infinitive.

Comment: Related: [grammar - The summer training or (just) summer training](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/17433/3281). (Look for the "two basic rules" under 62.1.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only the *indefinite* article *a/an* which cannot be used with plurals. That  word is a worn-down form of *one* and is used only with singular nouns. The equivalent determiner with plurals is the "empty" article (designated in linguistic texts with '∅')—that is, no article at all.

But it is perfectly OK to use the definite article *the* with plural nouns. *The* has no 'number': it is both singular and plural. It is used (in ***very*** general terms) to 'mark' an entity or collection of entities as *definite*: known, familiar, or in some way distinguished from the totality of similar entitities.

Comment: It's useful to think of "a" / "an" as a weakened form of "one".  It's also useful to think of "the" as a weakened form of "this" / "that" / "these" / "those".