# The article usage: The grassland

Tags: articles, zero-article

I can't decide whether to use *the* in these sentences.

> [The] white chalk rock underground  has formed  beautiful hills and  valleys.
>   [The] grassland has a lot of flowering plants.
>   [The] coastline has a lot of wondeful beaches and cliffs.

Comment: The "two basic rules" in [my old answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/17433/3281) could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a **particular** *something* then **the** should be used, otherwise the pluralised nouns (in your case) would be more general

> **The** grassland to the east has a lot of flowering plants. *(specific)*
>
> Grasslands have lots of flowering plants. *(general)*

If you use **the** with the plural, the listener will expect you to describe **which** grasslands (again being specific when using **the**)

> The grasslands of the Serengeti

Comment: 'The grassland' or 'the grasslands' are both grammatical. For example, "They raise cattle **on the grassland**, and sow the other half in wheat and forage for the herd." [(source)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grassland). "Annual rainfall **in the grasslands** is between 10 to 30 inches..." [(source)](http://www.mbgnet.net/sets/grasslnd/animals/). When to use a definite article is much more complex than your answer suggests.